# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in Laravel with Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, twilio

working with Laravel 10 and I have integrated Twilio sms sender with the application. I am using WAMP server and I have following loginController as well

```
public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required|numeric|min:10'
        ]);

        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'phone' => $request->phone
        ]);

        if(!$user) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Could not process a user with that Phone number.'], 401);
        }

        $user->notify(new LoginNeedsVerification());

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Text message notification sent.']);
    }
```

but when I try to make login browser inspect console response displayed following error messages

`message    "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`

`exception  "Twilio\\Exceptions\\EnvironmentException"`

`F:\2024\ride share app\backend\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php`

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: You will have to install local ssl certificate . After that it will be fixed. It will take much time to install ssl certificate. Best option is to use laragon. It has built in ssl certificate feature

Comment: how can do it and does it install to wamp server?

Comment: no. laragon is another alternative of wamp. It has built in php, nginx, apache, ssl features